# Input string not in a correct format

Tags: c#, console, int

I am new to c# and I was trying to convert a string into an int. I have seen similar posts but none of them worked out for me. I double checked to make sure that the type of data I want to convert is a string and also the string does include an integer with no space or other characters. I became out of options. here is a screenshot of my string :
[image]

I first extracted the number from the first string and "11" shows the final string I have. I then printed out its type to make sure it is a string but when I use Convert.ToInt32(drivers) it does not work and I keep getting input string not in the correct format error. Any help is appreciated.

Edit:

I added the code I am using below:

```
    Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", result);
    string s = result;
    int start = s.IndexOf("[[") + 2;
    int end = s.IndexOf("]]", start);
    string drivers = s.Substring(start, end - start);
    Console.WriteLine(drivers);
    Console.WriteLine(drivers.GetType());
    int t= Convert.ToInt32(drivers);
```

Comment: consider using a JSON parser.

Comment: Don't screenshot code please....

Comment: Remove the double quotes.

Comment: Please show us your code

Comment: Add your code, not screenshots of the console application.

Comment: I added my code to the original post. I looked at other posts and having double quotes should not cause a problem.

Comment: This is a giant mistake. Throw away all of your code and use a JSON parser as nature intended.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here:

```
int start = s.IndexOf("[[") + 2;
int end = s.IndexOf("]]", start);
```

You need to remove the `"` from there:

```
int start = s.IndexOf("[[\"") + 3;
int end = s.IndexOf("\"]]", start);
```

However, I strongly suggest you to use a JSON parser instead of this manual work.

Comment: That works perfectly. Thanks for the help. I will see what a JSON parser is. I just started coding in C# a few days ago as a newbee.

Comment: @Fatima https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Comment: @downvoter, care to comment?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you added later I guess you are taking  from the string a whole "11" with the double quotes, which makes it a STRING and not a number.

So the result is

```
Convert.ToInt32(""11""); //-> Fires Error.
```

Solution:

```
 int start = s.IndexOf("[[\"") + 3;
int end = s.IndexOf("\"]]", start);
string drivers = s.Substring(start, end - start);
```

Try this. It will return 11 and not "11".

All the suggestions they're giving you to use a JSON parser (Json.NET for example) are still a better option. Make your choiche.

Mark as answer if it helped.

Comment: "[["" will not result in a valid string. "[[\"" is what you are looking for

Comment: @FabianH. Fixed, thanks. +1 for you

Comment: Not completely fixed: you are using Index + 2 instead of + 3 (making it `"11`)

Comment: @FabianH. you are right. I tried that before myself and it did not work out.